# What curve does a stiff whisker flexing in oscillation due to inertia express?

Tags: classical-mechanics, spring, oscillators, home-experiment

Take a short length of stiff but flexible straight wire (I used ~5cm of ~0.1mm diameter brass) and hold it tightly at the base, then flick the tip. The wire will then rapidly oscillate in flexing back and forth, subtending a strange curved wedge shape that will shrink in angle as energy dissipates (presumably due to air resistance).

My question is, what's that shape? As in, what's the mathematical function?

It looks very much like log(|x|), but it can't be *exactly* that because the wire is held vertical at the base. Or is this a case where the idealization breaks down at the junction?

The tensile forces involved seem like they'd be a real pain to calculate, so perhaps it'd be better to simply take a heuristic approach, and experimentally measure the deflection with a camera and graph paper?

Comment: Take a look at Euler–Bernoulli beam theory, and dynamic beam equation. Usually for smaller deflections but is a start. Timoshenko beam theory takes more factors into account like shear. For the dynamics, there are ways to find the modes of oscillation and quality of the resonance. The camera is a good idea, but could also perhaps listen to the beam with a microphone, or electostatically optically monitor the position of the beam.  Micro-Electromechanical Machine (MEMs) devices often use cantilevers so the the behavior you are seeing can extend over many orders of magnitude.

Comment: So you are interested in the shape of the whisker at some point in its oscillation? I imagine that it's quite complicated because the various points along the whisker might not oscillate in phase with each other. Would it be a good idea to start with the static case: investigating the shape of the whisker when held with its end displaced from its natural position (its position when the whisker is straight) ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory#Large_deflections

Answer (score 0):

The initial case (static) is that of a cantilevered beam with a uniformly-distributed mass load per unit length. This is a solved problem and can be looked up in a table of solutions for beam deflections on-line; you may find one (a classic compilation) associated with the name *Timoshenko* and titled *Formulas For Stress And Strain*.

The dynamic case is also a solved problem called *tuning fork resonance*.